# Controling if condition in text change function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want if a user type the character "a" in textbox, message box with message "Ok" displays, and then textbox should clear.But I am facing the problem that when I type "a" message "Ok" is displays and along with message "No" is also displays.But when I remove the statment of clear then all goes good. Please tell me how to overcome this problem ?

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "a")
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Ok");
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("No");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `TextChanged` event of the textbox. When you change the text manually the `TextChanged` event runs again and this time the `else` expression runs.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{
  if(textBox1.Text != "")
    if (textBox1.Text == "a")
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Ok");
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("No");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because the `Text=""` triggered the `TextChanged` one more time. Use some flag like this:

```
bool suppressTextChanged;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if(suppressTextChanged) return;
  if (textBox1.Text == "a") {
    suppressTextChanged = true;
    textBox1.Text = "";
    suppressTextChanged = false; 
    MessageBox.Show("Ok");
  } else {
     MessageBox.Show("No");
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: The code above supposes you want to check against a string ("a" is just an example). If you want to check against a character. Use the `KeyPress` event instead.

Answer (score 1):

That is because when you set `textBox1.Text = "";` the event `textBox1_TextChanged` is raised one more and there is not a letter 'a' in the textbox and therefore a messasge box with "No" is also displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the change in textBox1.Text was from the user, or from you. "No" is displayed because you change the text to something ("") that is not "a". You could keep a boolean flag that indicates whether you want to react on the change:

```
bool changedByCode = false;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{
    if(changedByCode) return;

    if (textBox1.Text == "a")
    {
        changedByCode = true;
        textBox1.Text = "";
        changedByCode = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Ok");
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("No");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `textBox1.Text = ""` calls `textBox1_TextChanged` again.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle [`KeyUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx) event

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.KeyUp+=new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyUp);
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "a")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
                MessageBox.Show("Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No");
            }
        }
```